# I'm trying to deploy a web application on Windows Server 2016; it give me an error with Crystal Report (13.0.21)

Tags: crystal-reports

Error Message

````
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)). ```
````

Comment: error appeared when viewing report

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and [The perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).